# MonoDevelop not showing dll documentation for FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, monodevelop, xmldocument

I'm having a problem that has completely perplexed me, and I've tried everything I can think of.

Using MonoDevelop from trunk on GitHub on linux, Xml documentation doesn't work, but what's were weird is that it works for most DLLs, but doesn't for FluentNHibernate.

Ninject, Moq, NHibernate and the MVC library from MS work fine, it's just FluentNHibernate at the moment.

I did notice that Xml file for FluentNHibernate had an uppercase extension, which I changed, but it didn't fix it.  I also noticed that I had the pdb file in the directory too, removed that, still didn't work.

I've not got an idea what going wrong as all the others are working, just that one, and I can't find an issue with the xml file.  I also can't see a difference in the dll's after looking at them in the assembly browser.

Any ideas welcomed, I'll try anything.  This may also just be a bug with trunk but I don't have a stable version to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting this is in as an answer so that my steps are here for all to see.

I'm not entirely sure what solved it, but here's some things I did.

- Renamed the file extension to lowercase
- Deleted the reference and re-input it
- Restarted MonoDevelop
- Restarted the Machine

Not sure which one of them fixed it...